# Installing TikzEdt on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, windows-7

I switched from `Windows 7` to `Ubuntu 14.04` and want to install `TikZ` editor `TikzEdt` (See [here](http://www.tikzedt.org/) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/tikzedt/downloads/detail?name=TikzEdt_2_1_Linux.tar.gz&can=2&q=)). I would highly appreciate if someone explain me how to install it. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty simple, just follow the instructions provided at the second link ([here](https://code.google.com/p/tikzedt/downloads/detail?name=TikzEdt_2_1_Linux.tar.gz&can=2&q=)).

1. You need Mono and Latex, so run this command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mono-complete texlive-full
   ```
2. Then download the file provided at that page ([TikzEdt_2_1_Linux.tar.gz](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/tikzedt/TikzEdt_2_1_Linux.tar.gz))
3. Copy/paste the downloaded file to the location where you want to run it from.
4. Run:

   ```
   tar -xf TikzEdt_2_1_Linux.tar.gz
   ```

   in the same folder as the downloaded file.
5. Once it's finished extracting, run:

   ```
   ./tikzedt
   ```

You should be good to go!

Comment: (+1): Thanks @RPI for your answer. I accomplished upto point 4 but could not run `TikzEdt` using instructions given in 5. Any thoughts. Thanks

Comment: Okay, can you get into the directory where you extracted the .tar.gz file and give me the output of the `ls` command? Also, the output of the `ls` command in the directory where you downloaded the .tar.gz.

Comment: This is the output of ls command of the directory where I extracted the .tar.gz file, the same place where I downloaded the file.  `google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb   teamviewer_linux.deb
mendeleydesktop_1.12.3-stable_i386.deb  TikzEdt_2_1_Linux.tar.gz
Release                                 Tinn-R 1.17.2.4 setup.exe
rstudio-0.98.1091-i386.deb              Tinn-R 1.17.2.4 setup.rar`

Comment: @MYaseen208 Sorry about never getting back to you...I got busy. Have you figured it out yet? Otherwise, I can try and give you some more pointers to figure it out...

Comment: You fine @RPi. Yes I figured out it with your nice help. Thanks again. I've a new [question here](http://askubuntu.com/q/553525/283472). Would appreciate if you can help. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 All right! Always glad to help! I'll take a look at that other question as soon as I can!

Comment: `here` link is dead for instructions