# Texlive 2014 on Ubuntu 14.04: Font WebOMintsGD not found

Tags: 14.04, fonts, latex, texlive

I upgraded to `Texlive 2014` on `Ubuntu 14.04` and trying to install `non-freetonts` with the following commands:

```
  wget http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts
  sudo texlua install-getnonfreefonts
  getnonfreefonts -a
```

Then I used `getnonfreefonts-l` to check the installed fonts and this command shows `Webomints` font in this list.

Then I'm getting the this error

> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file WebOMintsGD): Font WebOMintsGD not
>   found

(Might be in different directory, looked [this link](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/sK0ydyiOYWwpKf22YGEx) for the same problem where fonts were in different directory). I'm not very expert and struggling with it. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: did you install the package as sudo apt-get install getnonfreefonts-sys?

Comment: Maybe helpful http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255599/74924